# Delphi 64 bit Indy OpenSSL libraries

Tags: delphi, ssl, openssl, 64-bit, indy

Trying to use Indy in a 64 bit app, with OpenSSL. The app has be ported from 32 bit. There everything worked fine with OpenSSL libraries downloaded from https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL

But I cannot find the 64 bit ones. Currently the repository at fulgan seems to be empty. Anyone has any info on that. I cannot make it work with standard OpenSSL binaries.

I am not sure if there were any changes regarding Indy on this.

Comment: There is some experimental builds: https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/Experimental/ or you can look for any precompiled binaries version 1.0.2: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries

Comment: Tried both and none seem to be working. Getting error on load. No clue why. 32 bit works without problems

Comment: http://wiki.overbyte.eu/arch/openssl-1.0.2p-win64.zip
This one is working :)

Comment: The problem is that the 32bit dll's have the exact same names as the 64bit dll's! Be sure you've got the right ones in the same folder as the exe (\debug\win32 or \debug\win64) folder, or they should be in the windows\sysWOW64 (32bit) and \windows\system32 (64bit) folders respectively.

Comment: Yes I know that. That was not the problem. Fulgan did not have the working 64 bit ones for some reason. I don't know if they still do new version. In the end the ICS repository had the working 64 bit versions that work with Indy

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you for a good answer. Clears up all problems. Make it a separate answers so I can accept it.

Comment: @Runner answer posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Currently the repository at fulgan seems to be empty

[Indy's OpenSSL DLLs were recently moved](https://www.indyproject.org/2020/06/16/openssl-binaries-moved-to-github/) to a new GitHub repo @ https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries, which includes both 32bit and 64bit files.

> I cannot make it work with standard OpenSSL binaries

Indy 10 works fine with standard OpenSSL binaries, PROVIDED that you are using OpenSSL 1.0.2 and not 1.1.x.  See https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/183 for the current state of Indy's 1.1.x support.  The main code does not support 1.1.x yet, but there is an experimental implementation pending review that you can try out.

Comment: Is a new version of 64-bit OpenSSL Indy available now?
I wanted to create a DLL for SMTP authentication using a DHparam key - the library is to be used by an application in C# NET 6.0, also 64-bit (there is no external software available in C# for the DH key file that Indy uses?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77243028/how-migrate-key-reading-dh-pem-in-delphi-indy-ssl-to-c-sharp-on-net-6-0