# How migrate key reading DH-Pem in Delphi-Indy-SSL to C# on .NET 6.0?

Tags: delphi, openssl, .net-6.0, indy, diffie-hellman

dhparam.par

```
-----BEGIN DH PARAMETERS-----
...==
-----END DH PARAMETERS-----
```

Indy OpenSSL:

```
object IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL
Destination = 'smtp.server:587'
Host = 'smtp.server'
MaxLineAction = maException
Port = 587
DefaultPort = 0
SSLOptions.DHParamsFile = 'dhparam.pem'
SSLOptions.Method = sslvTLSv1_2
SSLOptions.SSLVersions = [sslvTLSv1_2]
SSLOptions.Mode = sslmUnassigned
SSLOptions.VerifyMode = []
SSLOptions.VerifyDepth = 0
```

*What default of other settings will Indy OpenSSL read then? Autodetection?*

How to read this file dhparam.par in C# on .NET 6.0?

```
byte[] dhParams = LoadKey(DhParamsFilePath);
var diffieHellman = new ECDiffieHellmanCng()
                    diffieHellman.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
                    diffieHellman.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;

                    diffieHellman.ImportParameters(new ECParameters
                    {
                        Q = new ECPoint
                        {
                            X = dhParams, 
                            Y = dhParams
                        },
                        Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves. ????
                });
```

Is there any clever NuGet that would read this analogously to Delphi Indy OpenSSL?

Comment: I don't know if there's something available in dotnet to read this file format -- BouncyCastle, my usual go-to, does have a PEMReader for _many_ PEM formats but NOT this one. But even if you read it, you definitely can't use the parameters for _classic_ DH, now retronymed FFDH for clarity, in ECDH -- they use completely different types of mathematics. (For one thing FFDH does not have or use any kind of 'point', while ECDH absolutely requires a curve point.) On top of which the _Windows_ cryptoproviders only support a few standardized aka 'named' curves, not 'custom' ones.

Comment: In fact in this decade there's almost no good reason to still be using FFDH parameters -- and (FF)DHE ciphersuites or keyexchange -- at all; practically everything now supports and usually prefers or even requires ECDHE.

Comment: The problem is that I have a DH key, I have an smtp server and Delphi Indy OpenSSL projects that run it, and I wanted to use it in a new C# project. Unfortunately, I won't change either the key or SMTP :-(

Comment: I made an OpenSLL-enabled Indy DLL with a DHparam key file, but unfortunately it is 32-bit, which limits the application in C# .NET 6.0. I'm not sure if Indy is already 64-bit for stable use:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62530135/delphi-64-bit-indy-openssl-libraries

Comment: Your file is (FF)DH parameters -- as the PEM label says -- NOT A KEY. If used at all (only for FFDHE suites below 1.3) it generates a new and different key on every full handshake (i.e. every non-resumption connection), so there is no reason a new server should use the same FFDHE params, and as I said it probably doesn't need any at all. (If you want the new server to replace the old one 'seamlessly' you _may_ need to use the same cert and chain and static signing key matching that cert, but none of those are FFDHE parameters or in your DHparam file.)

Comment: In fact I'm not clear now if your Indy code is the server or the client. If it's a client talking TO the smtp server, it doesn't use these DH parameters at all, for anything, ever. And neither will any dotNET client you can write. Only a TLS server (below 1.3) ever uses FFDHE parameters, never a client.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Savior, you are right :-)
I turned it off:
//IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.DHParamsFile:='dhparam.pem';
And the email was sent correctly. Now I can try to repeat the same in C# .NET 6.0 :-)